# rummy card placement on canvas

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am trying to place 5 cards overlapping 30% on one another. and trying to give a movement to it using mouse events . It should drop within the 5 cards only, not outside of that.
I have learned the drag and drop events and executed it, but i cannot place the card within the 5 cards .
Please somebody help me in this.  Please Check the Below Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"     creationComplete="carcan();">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[

        import mx.containers.Canvas;
        import mx.controls.Image;

        private var images:Array;
        private var images1:Array;
        private const IMAGE_COUNT:uint = 5;
        private var img:Image;
        private var img1:Image;


        private var points:flash.geom.Point;
        private var offset_x:int;
        private var offset_y:int;
        private var canal:Canvas;
        private var doDrag:Boolean;

        [Embed(source='cards/2C.png')]
        private var Image0:Class;

        [Embed(source='cards/2D.png')]
        private var Image1:Class;

        [Embed(source='cards/2H.png')]
        private var Image2:Class;

        [Embed(source='cards/2S.png')]
        private var Image3:Class;

        [Embed(source='cards/3C.png')]
         private var Image4:Class;

         public function carcan():void
         {
            canal = new Canvas();
            canal.setStyle("backgroundColor","blue");
            canal.x=100;
            canal.y=50;
            canal.width=500;
            canal.height=400;
            this.addChild(canal);
            init();
         }

         public function init():void
         {
          images = new Array(IMAGE_COUNT);
             for (var i:int = 0; i < IMAGE_COUNT; i++)
                {
                     img= new Image();
                     img1= new Image();
                        images[i] = this["Image" + i];
                        trace(images[i]);

                img.x=(i*30)+50;
                img.source=images[i];
                img.id="Image"+i;
                canal.addChild(img);


                 img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, md);
                img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mm);
                canal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,smu);
                img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mu);

                                        }

         }
         public function smu(event:MouseEvent):void
         {
            img.alpha=1;
            img.stopDrag();
            doDrag=false;
            setCards(); 

         }

         public function mo(event:MouseEvent):void
         {

            if(doDrag==true)
            {

            img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, md);
            img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mu);
            img.stopDrag();
            img.alpha=1;
            img.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mm);
            }
            else
            {
            img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mm);
            }




         }                 

         public function md(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

        img = new Image();
            doDrag=true;

              canal.setChildIndex(Image(event.target),images.length-1);
             img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mm);



        }
        public function mm(event:MouseEvent):void
        {


             if(doDrag==true)
             {
                points = new Point();
            images = new Array(IMAGE_COUNT);


            img = new Image();
            img = Image(event.target);

            points.x=event.target.x;
            points.y=event.target.y;
            points = localToGlobal(points);
            img.x=points.x;
            img.y=points.y;
             img.alpha=0.7;
            img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mu);                  
            var boundar:flash.geom.Rectangle = new Rectangle(this.x, this.y, 250, 100);

             }
        }


        public function mu(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            img.alpha=1;
            canal.stopDrag();
            doDrag=false;

            canal.stopDrag();
            doDrag=false;
            var current:Image = event.currentTarget as Image;
            var num1:int = current.x;                   

    if(num1 < 50){

         canal.setChildIndex(current, images.length-5);
         current.y=0;
         setCards();                
        }
    if(num1 > 50 && num1 < 80){

         canal.setChildIndex(current, images.length-4);
         current.y=0;
         setCards();                
        }
    if(num1 > 80 && num1 < 110){

    canal.setChildIndex(current, images.length-3);
    current.y=0;
        setCards(); 
        }
    if(num1 > 110 && num1 < 140){
        canal.setChildIndex(current, images.length-2);

         current.y=0;
        setCards(); 
        }
    if(num1 > 140 && num1 < 170){
        canal.setChildIndex(current, images.length-2);

         current.y=0;
        setCards(); 
        }
    if(num1 > 170){

        canal.setChildIndex(current, images.length-1);
        current.y=0;
        setCards(); 
        }



        }
        private function setCards():void{
        var b:int = 0;
        var a:int;
        var cardsArray:Array = canal.getChildren();
        for(a = 0;a < cardsArray.length; a++)
        {
            canal.getChildAt(a).x = 50+b;
            b=b+30;
            canal.getChildAt(a).y=0;
        }
         }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>        
</mx:Application>
```

PS: I am trying to replace the drag and drop events with mouse events and get the same functionality using mouse events. Please somebody help me in this.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking.  Is your problem with the initial layout of the cards on the canvas?  **WHAT** should drop within the 5 cards only?  What code did you execute related to drag and drop events?  What card are you trying to place within the five cards?  And where are you trying to place it?

Comment: I have edited the question and also added my code, on which i am struggling since many days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope Below Code may help you: - You can use Drag and drop as per below code and create it in AS. I have created it in MXML which will give you some idea what you are looking for: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:local="*">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.DragSource;
            import mx.core.UIComponent;
            import mx.events.DragEvent;
            import mx.managers.DragManager;

            private function doDragEnter(event:DragEvent):void
            {
                DragManager.acceptDragDrop(UIComponent(event.target));
            }

            private function doDragDrop(event:DragEvent):void
            {
                var img:RummyItemRenderer;
                if (event.dragInitiator.parent == mainCanvas)
                {
                    img = event.dragInitiator as RummyItemRenderer;

                    //mainCanvas.swapChildren(img, event.currentTarget as RummyItemRenderer);

                    var index:Number = mainCanvas.getChildIndex(event.currentTarget as RummyItemRenderer);


                    mainCanvas.removeChild(img);
                    mainCanvas.addChildAt(img,index);

                    setCardsPosition();
                }
            }

            private function setCardsPosition():void{
                var b:int = 0;
                var a:int;
                var cardsArray:Array = mainCanvas.getChildren();
                for(a = 0;a < cardsArray.length; a++)
                {
                    mainCanvas.getChildAt(a).x = 50+b;
                    b = b+30;
                    mainCanvas.getChildAt(a).y=20;
                }
            }

            private function doDragStart(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var dragInitiator:RummyItemRenderer = event.currentTarget as RummyItemRenderer;
                var dragSource:DragSource = new DragSource();
                DragManager.doDrag(dragInitiator, dragSource, event);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Canvas id="mainCanvas" backgroundColor="#DDDDDD" width="400" height="200" x="50" y="50">

        <local:RummyItemRenderer id="firstID" x="{mainCanvas.x}" y="20" width="200" height="80%" backgroundColor="#FF0000"
                                  mouseDown="doDragStart(event)" dragEnter="doDragEnter(event)" dragDrop="doDragDrop(event)"
                                  setImageSource="myImageURL"/>
        <local:RummyItemRenderer id="secondID" x="{mainCanvas.x + 30}" y="20" width="200" height="80%" backgroundColor="#00FF00"
                                 mouseDown="doDragStart(event)" dragEnter="doDragEnter(event)" dragDrop="doDragDrop(event)"
                                 setImageSource="myImageURL"/>
        <local:RummyItemRenderer id="thirdID" x="{mainCanvas.x + 60}" y="20" width="200" height="80%" backgroundColor="#0000FF"
                                 mouseDown="doDragStart(event)" dragEnter="doDragEnter(event)" dragDrop="doDragDrop(event)"
                                 setImageSource="myImageURL"/>
    </mx:Canvas>

</s:Application>
```

RummyItemRenderer.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            [Bindable]
            private var _setImageSource:String;

            public function get setImageSource():String
            {
                return _setImageSource;
            }

            public function set setImageSource(sourceURL:String):void
            {
                _setImageSource = sourceURL;
            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Image id="imageID" source="{_setImageSource}"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
from left to right  direction the movement is correct, but when i move the cards(images) from right to left  direction, its not dropping.

Comment: The images are getting swapped. It just need to drop at particular position,but it should not swap.

Comment: Thanks for the concern. But can you tell(or teach) me why right-left movement is not working correctly compare to left-right movement. Please, accept my apology if my response is offensive.

Comment: Have you checked above modified code? i have commented swapping and added some line of code and it is working for both right-left and left-right movement for card/color. please let me know what i missed in it.. might be my understanding is wrong.. as per my assumption -- you want to move card left to right and right to left on drag and It should drop within the 5 cards only, not outside of that. if you want to drop "x item" in index 2 you will drag "x item" on 1 and perform Drop operation right? now if it get drop than you have to change position of all index 2,3,4 etc but not of 0 and 1

Comment: Yes, the code is working correctly as needed. Just when i drag from right to left its taking many drags to perform the drag event. left-right is working smoothly with no multiple dragging required. Let me Thank you again, your code is completely right and working, just clearing my doubt. Thanks once again.

Comment: I just observed a small problem with the above code, the dropping is being done where the mouse cursor is not by the card's X position. Its taking the vale of mouse cursor and dropping the card. What it should do is its should take the X value of card and drop at particular position.

Comment: That's correct... as per my assumption you are looking for mouse cursor position and not card x position.... i believe that not big change.... enjoy...